# Copy images from one folder to another

Tags: php

My Web application stored in directory of XAMPP/htdocs/projectname/. And I have images(source) & img(destination) folders in above directory.I am writing following line of code to get the copy images from one folder to another. But I get the following Warnnigs: **(Warning: copy(Resource id #3/image1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs)**  and images are not copied into destination.

```
<?php
        $src = opendir('../images/');
    $dest = opendir('../img/');
    while($readFile = readdir($src)){
            if($readFile != '.' && $readFile != '..'){
                 if(!file_exists($readFile)){
                if(copy($src.$readFile, $dest.$readFile)){
                echo "Copy file";
            }else{
                    echo "Canot Copy file";
                }
                   }
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: make sure you set the right permissions to destination folder

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess (sorry) but I don't believe you can use `$src = opendir(...)` and `$src.$readFile` like that. Try doing this:

```
$srcPath = '../images/';
$destPath = '../img/';  

$srcDir = opendir($srcPath);
while($readFile = readdir($srcDir))
{
    if($readFile != '.' && $readFile != '..')
    {
        /* this check doesn't really make sense to me,
           you might want !file_exists($destPath . $readFile) */
        if (!file_exists($readFile)) 
        {
            if(copy($srcPath . $readFile, $destPath . $readFile))
            {
                echo "Copy file";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Canot Copy file";
            }
        }
    }
}

closedir($srcDir); // good idea to always close your handles
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your code, this will work definitely.

```
if(copy("../images/".$readFile, "../img/".$readFile))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are giving wrong path ,if path of  your file say script.php is "XAMPP/htdocs/projectname/script.php" and images and img both are in "projectname" folder than you should use following values for $srcPath and $destPath,change their values to

```
$srcPath = 'images/';
$destPath = 'img/';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getImage()
  {

    $Path='image/'; //complete image directory path
    $destPath = '/edit_image/';
    // makes new folder, if not exists.
    if(!file_exists($destPath) || file_exists($destPath)) 
    {
        rmdir($destPath);
        mkdir($destPath, 0777);
    }

    $imageName='abc.jpg';
    $Path=$Path.$imageName;
    $dest=$destPath.$imageName;
    if(copy($Path, $dest));
  }
```